# How can I open my Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I had a Minecraft creative world that I had spent 10-20 hours on. I decided to create my own addon using Bridge which work fine until one time after trying to load the world Minecraft closed. I reopened Minecraft and tried loading the world again but Minecraft closed again. Looking at task manager I can see the GPU dropped to 0% then spiked to 100%. I repeated this and the same thing happened again and again.
Things I have tried:

- Removing the addon
- Copying the world and then trying to load it
- Trying to open it on my brother's laptop

None of these worked. Could anyone tell my how to load and play on my world and/or how to prevent this from happening again in the future.

Comment: Have you changed your account and use the world?

Comment: @Jmooroof I have used my brothers account.

Comment: Have you tried removing the addon and then copying it without the addon?

Comment: @Zyxilef Yes I have.